# Symfony2 - How is the priority setting of a security voter used by the AccessDecisionManager?

Tags: symfony, authorization, acl

I've seen [here on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security.xml#L112) that the default configuration use priority tags like following:

```
<service id="security.access.simple_role_voter" class="%security.access.simple_role_voter.class%" public="false">
    <tag name="security.voter" priority="245" />
</service>
```

I can't find any reference to this "priority" inside the [AccessDecisionManager](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php) itself.

What impact on the decision process does the `priority` setting have ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The listener/voter with higher priority is executed first.

The following rules apply to listener priorities:

> priority [...]
> defaults to 0.
>
> This value can be from -255 to 255, and the listeners
> will be executed in the order of their priority (**highest to lowest**).

(See: [How to create an Event Listener.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html))

---

**app/config/security.yml**

The `security.access_decision_manager` setting defines the strategy used for the final decision:

```
security:
    access_decision_manager: 
        strategy: affirmative # <- strategy setting
```

There are 3 strategies available:

- `unanimous` - 1 single voter denies access.
- `affirmative` - 1 single voter grants access.
- `consensus` - Majority wins.

(See: [Changing the access decision strategy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html#changing-the-access-decision-strategy))

---

A voter's decision is expressed by the return value of it's `vote()` method. example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;

public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $post, array $attributes)
{
    // ...
    
    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
}
```

- `VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED` The authorization will be granted by this voter;
- `VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN` The voter cannot decide if authorization should be granted;
- `VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED` The authorization will be denied by this voter.

(See: [How to use voters to check user permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html))

Comment: But every voter is executed all right? As far as I understand it's priority about execution order, it doesn't make the decision weight of a voter more important than another isn't it?

Comment: Every voter is executed as long as it's tagged with `security.voter` and the final decision hasn't been made. A voter doesn't have a _weight_ but the decision manager has a configurable **strategy** ... I've added more information about this decision strategy to my answer.

Comment: Okay I understand better, actually existing strategies doesn't fit my needs, so I thought that using priority could solve my problem. But it doesn't. Maybe I have to create my own strategy or my own decisionManager...

Comment: dirty but quick: You can just register the same voter with the container multiple times (i.e. by just increasing a suffixed number of the service-name) using a compiler pass ... then use the `consensus` strategy to mimic a simple `weight` function. Got the idea? Or (clean way) override and extend the access_decision_manager itself, adding a weight attribute that's taken into account during the decision process.

Comment: Be aware that the quote is wrong yet. From the doc: "your own listeners can use any positive or negative integer."